# centrar dos botones en bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Soy nuevo y aunque he estado leyendo comentarios de otros hilos, no doy exactamente con lo que busco. Necesito colocar dos botones en medio de un div que ocupa toda la pantalla, lo estoy haciendo con bootstrap y no tengo mucha idea. seria algo como esto,[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo HTML:

```
<div class="trans"> 
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btninter">Contacta</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btninter right">Proyectos</button> 
</div> -----El div trans es simplemente para ubicarme----
```

Mi estilo:

```
.centerbtn{ 
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; left:0;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    /*position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(30%); width: 100%;*/
}
```

Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Por favor añade el html y CSS que tienes hasta ahora.

Comment: No se muy bien como mostrarlo para que sea más legible.

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el resultado que esperas.

Comment: He probado con un div ajustado al tamaño de los botones y un margin:0 auto, pero no me lo centra. Querría centrar los dos botones en medio de un div que tengo ahí.

Comment: Cual version de bootstrap estas usando?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de manera muy simple usando flexbox. Por ejemplo, le pones a tu div con la clase `trans` la propiedad `display: flex;` y justificas su contenido al centro mediante `justify-content: center;`.

Ejemplo:

```css
.trans{
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="trans"> 
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btninter centrado">Contacta</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btninter right centrado">Proyectos</button> 
</div>
```

**¡¡Importante!!:** En el CSS que proporcionas en tu pregunta pones los estilos en la clase `.centerbtn` pero realmente no se la estás asociando a ningún elemento. Ten cuidado con esto porque si no lo asocias a ningún elemento es como si esa clase de CSS no existiera ya que no va  realizar ninguna modificación.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo pruebo y te comento. Es que como dije, lo he sometido a muchos cambios y ya no se ni lo que se está aplicando :S. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @KelianBorge No te preocupes que todo se arregla :) Esperaré tu respuesta ^^

Answer (score 1):

Envuelva el botón en div con la clase "text-center".

```
<div class="text-center"> 
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btninter">Contacta</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btninter right">Proyectos</button> 
</div>
```

EJEMPLO:

```
<!-- correcto -->
<div class="trans text-center"> 
    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Next Step!</button> 
</div>
```